# Ban redistribution, but still allow code changes?

Tags: licensing, open-source

I have an app that was created from a follow-along tutorial. I was first using the Apache license for it until some people began to copy the code, insert ads and then redistribute the app. Would there be a license that allows for code changes but bans redistribution?

Comment: intersting question and commentary.  I see @ThomasOwen 's answer, and it's a good start.  I wonder if you couple that with DMCA filings with google saying by monetizing the app they violate your agreement.  You aren't going to be able to file legal cases in India and South Africa to defend your product against global users making minor changes, but you can get google to take it down if it violates DMCA (but other violation types you may be in trouble too -- if you just wanted an "injunction" for a non-DMCA violation, you'd probably need a judge to tell google to take it down)

Comment: If he released it as Apache Licensed, there's not a lot the OP can do as the behaviors the OP mentioned meet the terms of the license.  All he can do is release his changes under a new license and hope to prevent issues in the future.  But that may be closing the barn door after the horses escaped.

Comment: Sue yourself for including your copywrited stuff in your open source app, then sue the people using the apps source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The license that you describe does not meet the [Open Source Initiative's definition of open source](https://opensource.org/osd). According to that definition, an open source license can not restrict someone who selling a software product. You won't find an existing open-source license that meets your criteria.

However, if you hire a lawyer with the appropriate expertise, you can have an appropriate license written.

Comment: That's okay. This app is yet still worthless so I don't have to call a lawyer. One question though - how can open-source not prevent somebody from selling a copy of the software? All major open-source software has some kind of 'If you paid for this, then you were scammed' discretion, with a message to 'Report it immediately if found.' Why doesn't it apply to my app?

Comment: "how can open-source not prevent somebody from selling a copy of the software" Because the Open Source Definition, which defines what "Open Source" means, says so. Open Source is about freedom, including the freedom to charge as much or as little for the software as you want.

Comment: @ideaman924 By definition, there is nothing illegal about selling open source software. However, if you sell someone an open source program that they can just as easily get for free, *and you aren't adding any additional value over the free download* (e.g. providing tech support or a physical CD) then every sale you get relies on the consumer being totally uninformed, which is only likely to happen if you actively hide the fact that there's a free version. Presumably "adding additional value" is the sort of thing one can't produce a legally precise definition for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any general license that operates under such rules, since it goes against the ethos that so-called "Open Source" licenses are trying to create (q.v. the Open Source Initiative's [definition](https://opensource.org/osd)). However, freedom to modify without freedom to distribute is moderately common in commercial contracts, so it's not a legal impossibility, and knocking up a theoretically enforceable "crayon license" that precludes redistribution whilst permitting modification doesn't seem too hard. You could even enrich a lawyer by having one carefully drafted.

Your bigger problem is that it is *functionally* meaningless without any means to enforce it; the kind of unscrupulous cad that makes their pennies by slapping ads into Apache or GPL licensed code are unlikely to be deterred by a license that they know won't be enforced.